# Why my leftsideBar doesn't work? in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to make sidenav with angular material.

```
<div class="example-tabs-500-height elements-sidebar-example ">test1<!-- right sidebar -->


<section layout="row" flex>

    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left"
                md-disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4">

        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
            <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Disabled Backdrop</h1>
        </md-toolbar>

        <md-content layout-margin>
            <p>
                This sidenav is not showing any backdrop, where users can click on it, to close the sidenav.
            </p>

        </md-content>

    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex layout-padding>

        <div layout="column" layout-align="top center">
            <p>
                Developers can also disable the backdrop of the sidenav.<br/>
                This will disable the functionality to click outside to close the sidenav.
            </p>

            <div>
                <md-button ng-click='toggleLeft("left")' class="md-raised">
                    Toggle Sidenavs
                </md-button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </md-content>

</section>
```

and in controller:

$scope.toggleLeft = toggleLeft;
       // $scope.toggleRight = buildToggler('right');

```
    function toggleLeft(componentId) {
        console.log('toogle');
        return function() {
            $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
        }
    }
```

Function toggleLeft writes in console 'toogle'.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning a function?

```
function() {
    $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
}
```

Shou be only:

```
function toggleLeft(componentId) {
    console.log('toogle');
    $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Take a look on this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEJOzg